# Как зафиксировать ориентацию только одного фрагмента?

Tags: android, android-fragment

В приложении одна основная активность и несколько фрагментов. Мне нужно, чтобы один из фрагментов (MyLandscapeFragment) всегда был в альбомной ориентации, а остальные на выбор сенсора устройства.
В манифесте указано:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

В основной активности реализовано:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // ***
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        startMyLandscapeFragment();
    }
    // ***
}
```

Чтобы запустить MyLandscapeFragment, перед этим я вызываю

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

что в свою очередь передается в `onConfigurationChanged`, откуда запускается нужный фрагмент.
Если после этого выйти из приложения, нажав один раз кнопку назад, затем заново запустить, повторный вызов `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)` ни к чему не приведет, `onConfigurationChanged` не вызовется, ориентация не изменится.